# Are helpers really faster than partials? What about string building?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, string, helper, partials

I've got a fancy-schmancy "worksheet" style view in a Rails app that is taking way too long to load. (In dev mode, and yes I know there's no caching there, "Completed in 57893ms (View: 54975, DB: 855)") The worksheet is rendered using helper methods, because I couldn't stand maintaining umpteen teeny little partials for the different sorts of rows in the worksheet. Now I'm wondering whether partials might actually be faster?

I've profiled the page load and identified a few cases where object caching will shave a few seconds off, but the profile output suggests that a large chunk of time is spent simply looping through the Worksheet model's constituent objects and appending the string output from the helper. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
def header_row(wksht)
  content_tag(:thead, :class => "ioe") do
    content_tag(:tr) do
      html_row = []
      for i in (0...wksht.class::NUM_COLS) do
        html_row << content_tag(:th, h(wksht.column_headings[i].upcase),
                                :class => wksht.column_classes[i])
      end
      html_row.join("\n")
    end
  end
end
```

OTOH using partials means opening files, spinning off the Ruby interpreter, and in the long run, aggregating a bunch of strings, right? So I'm wondering whether there is another way to speed things up in the helpers. Should I be using something like a stringstream (does that exist in Ruby?), should I get rid of content_tag calls in favor of my own "" string interpolation... I'm willing to write my own performance tests, and share the results, if you have any suggested alternatives to the approach I've already taken.

As it's a fairly complex view (and has an editable version as well), I'd rather not rewrite-and-profile the whole thing more than once. :)

Some related reading:

http://www.viget.com/extend/helpers-vs-partials-a-performance-question/ (old)
http://www.breakingpointsystems.com/community/blog/ruby-string-processing-overhead/
http://blog.purepistos.net/index.php/2008/07/14/benchmarking-ruby-string-interpolation-concatenation-and-appending/

**@tadman:**
There are row totals and column totals (and more columnar arithmetic), and since they're not all just totals, but also depend on other "magic numbers" from the database, I implemented them in the Ruby code rather than Javascript. (DRY and unit testable.) Javascript is used only in the edit view, and just to add/delete rows (client side only) and to fetch a sheet with fresh totals when the cell contents change. It fetches the whole table because nearly half of the values get updated when an input cell changes.

The worksheet and its rows are actually virtual models; they don't live in the DB, but rather aggregate a boatload of real AR objects. They get created every time a view renders (but that takes 1.7 secs in dev mode, so I'm not worried about it).

I suppose I could transmit a matrix of numbers, rather than marked-up content, and have JS unpack it into the sheet. But that gets unmaintainable fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up reading an excellent article at http://www.infoq.com/articles/Rails-Performance ("A Look At Common Performance Problems In Rails"). Then I followed the author's suggestion to cache computations during request processing:

```
def estimated_costs
  @estimated_costs ||=
    begin
      # tedious vector math
    end
end
```

Because my worksheet does stuff like the above over and over, and then builds on those results to calculate some more rows, this resulted in a **90% speedup** right off the bat. Should have been plain as day, but it started with just a few totals, then I showed the prototype to the customer, and it snowballed from there :)

I also wondered whether my array-based math might be inefficient, so I replaced the Ruby Arrays of numbers with NArray (http://narray.rubyforge.org/). The speedup was negligible but the code's cleaner, so it's staying that way.

Finally, I put some object caching in place. The "magic numbers" in the database only change a few times a year at most, and some of them are encrypted, but they need to be used in most of the calculations. That's low-hanging fruit ripe for caching, and it shaved off another 1.25 seconds.

I'll look at eager loading of associations next, as there's probably some time to save there, and I'll do a quick comparison of sending "just the data" vs sending the HTML, as @tadman suggested. About the only partial I can cache is the navigation sidebar. All of the other content depends on the request parameters.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

Internally all partials are translated into a block of executable Ruby code and run through exactly the same runtime as any helper methods. Periodically you can see glimpses of this when a malformed template causes the generated code to fail to compile.

Although it stands to reason that helper methods are faster than partials, and a straightforward string interpolation is faster still, it's hard to say if the performance gain from this would make it worth pursuing. Rendering a very large number of partials can be a bottleneck in terms of logging in the development environment, but in a production environment their impact seems less severe.

The only way to figure this one out is to benchmark your pages using two different rendering methods.

As you point out, caching is where you get the big gains. Using Memcached to save large chunks of pre-rendered HTML content can give you exponentially faster load times. Rendering 10,000 rows into HTML will always be slower than retrieving the same snippet from the `Rails.cache` subsystem.

It's also the case that the content you don't render is always rendered the quickest, so anything you can do to reduce the amount of content you generate for each helper call will provide big gains. If you're building a large spread-sheet style app that's entirely dependent on JavaScript, you may find that bundling up the data as a JSON array and expanding it client-side is significantly faster than unrolling the HTML on the server and shipping it over that way.

Comment: (See above for more info -- comment field is too small)

Does your last paragraph suggest that over-the-wire data transfer is a problem? I don't think it is in this context. Usually takes less than a second to pull a large page (through the firewall no less), and my server's on the same subnet as the client machine.

Comment: What might look like a simple template can expand into 500KB of HTML if you're doing some kind of geometric expansion on your data, such as X*Y where when X and Y are small the page is very small, but when X and Y get large the page gets enormous. The less HTML you generate and send, the faster your page will be. At 500KB/s transmission speed, which is typical, you can easily save 500ms by shaving a large page down to just the data and trimming 250KB from your output.